# Python bizarre class problem

Tags: python, overriding

I have the following piece of code where I try to override a method:

```
import Queue
class PriorityQueue(Queue.PriorityQueue):
    def put(self, item):
        super(PriorityQueue, self).put((item.priority, item))
```

However, when I run it I get `TypeError` exception:

```
super() argument 1 must be type, not classobj
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Queue.PriorityQueue` is not a new-style class, and `super` [only works with new-style classes](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#super). You must use

```
import Queue
class PriorityQueue(Queue.PriorityQueue):
    def put(self, item):
        Queue.PriorityQueue.put(self,(item.priority, item))
```

instead.

Comment: actually, you will also need to pass 'self' explicitly: Queue.PriorityQueue.put(self, (item.priority, item))